# scrolling jerky before braking when single edittext inside scrollview

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

I'm writing a simple text editor in my app. Accordingly, I need to scroll through a large editable text.

My layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/note"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>
</ScrollView>
```

In my Activity I set large text :

```
public class FileEditorActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_editor);

        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.note);

        text.setText(newText);    ////// LARGE TEXT
    }
}
```

Now, text scrolls but when the scroll speed is reduced scrolling starts to twitch (jerky)!!!!!!
I thought why so ......... And try the following :

```
scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll);
scrollView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
scrollView.setFocusable(true);
scrollView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
scrollView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          v.requestFocusFromTouch();
          if (text.hasFocus()) {
              text.clearFocus();
          }

          return false;
    }
});
```

And after that (when edittext always lost focus before scrolling) scroll large text working perfect when the scroll speed is reduced.

But I need to always stay in focus and maintain the state of the cursor when scrolling text ((((

How to do it ?????????

P.S. I want to like this :

***ES Explorer app*** 
When open text file on edit

[image]

Thanks in advance !!!!